# Setting HTML check box to check using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a constructor that creates a series of checkboxes inside a loop.

I am trying to set the checkboxes to checked, but it is not working.

The code is below:

```
function customMultiSelect(pDiv, pOptions, inputID, currentSelected)
{        
    this.Div = pDiv;
    this.options = pOptions;    
    this._initialise();

    for (var idxOption = 0; idxOption < pOptions.length; idxOption++) {

        var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.style.width = "30px";
        checkbox.style.border = "none";
        checkbox.style.float = "right";

        if (pOptions[idxOption] != "") {
            var arrTemp2 = pOptions[idxOption].split(",");
            var sText = arrTemp2[0];

            if (arrTemp2.length > 1) {
                sText = arrTemp2[1];
            }

            checkbox.value = arrTemp2[0];
            checkbox.id = inputID + "|" + idxOption;
            checkbox.checked = true;
            var textLabel = document.createElement("label");
            textLabel.appendChild(checkbox);
            textLabel.innerHTML += arrTemp2[1];
            textLabel.style.display = "block";
            textLabel.style.clear = "right";

        }

        this.Div.appendChild(textLabel);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put checked attribute instead of checkbox.checked = true; :

```
checkbox.setAttribute('checked', true);
```

Comment: That does not work, the object does not support that property

Comment: what browser you use?

Comment: Internet explorer and compatibility mode is on

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you use `textLabel.innerHTML += arrTemp2[1];` so that the HTML is rewritten and parsed. Before that you use `checkbox.checked = true` only manipulates the DOM property, while in HTML it's only `<input type="checkbox">`, so the result is `textLabel.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox">' + arrTemp2[1];`, gives you an unchecked checkbox again.

You should use `checkbox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked')`, then the HTML will be `<input type="checkbox" checked>`, in such case  `textLabel.innerHTML += arrTemp2[1];` equals `textLabel.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">' + arrTemp2[1];`

---

About the difference between HTML attribute and DOM property:

`setAttribute` actually manipulates the HTML attribute. If a DOM property is not set, the attribute will populate to the property. However, when property is set, change attribute will not affect property. For example you have a input tag:

```
<input type="text" value="asdf">
```

And you input something in the field, say "qwer", then you will see the difference

```
document.querySelector('input').value // "qwer"
document.querySelector('input').getAttribute('value') // "asdf"
```

And when you change its attribute

```
document.querySelector('input').setAttribute('value', 'zxcv')
```

You will not see any change in the page, because `document.querySelector('input').value` is still "qwer". The change actually takes place in HTML, open devtool you will see:

```
<input type="text" value="zxcv">
```

And finally, its the **DOM property** sent out when you submit a form, not the attribute.